# Choosing machine id when compiling kernel

Tags: linux, arm, bootloader, stm32

I need to compile the kernel for **stm32f429** and I need to set the machine id of 
**stm32f429** to 1. The default machine id is **0xffffffff (-1)**.

How do I change it?

Comment: Please share the code you have tried so far

Comment: Don't the supported ARMv7-M platforms all boot via DT? ([arch/arm/mach-stm32/](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mach-stm32) certainly does.) The legacy ATAGS machine number ought to be irrelevant - what are you doing that makes it necessary?